# jQuery UI Dialog + External Content w/AJAX not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, external

**My goal:** upon clicking a link, I want to load an external page (with a image upload form) into a jQuery UI Dialog and have it submitted AJAX style.

**My problem:** The dialog loads the external PHP page just fine and I'm able to submit the form via AJAX -- using the jQuery form plugin shown here http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ -- BUT for some reason the AJAX submission won't work inside the dialog box, only when I view the page directly. It simply loads the page itself as if the JS was turned off or something.

Here's the parent page displaying the dialog:

### port_edit.php (header)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshWindow(){
        location.reload(true);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery-display').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Gallery Display',
                width: 280,
                height: 280,
                close: refreshWindow,
                resizable: false

            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });


    });
});
    </script>
```

### port_edit.php (link)

```
<a href="image_upload.php" id="gallery-display">Modify</a>
```

**And the external document loaded into the dialog:**

### image_upload.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        // attach handler to form's submit event
        $('#image-upload').submit(function() { 
            // submit the form 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
            return false;
        });        }); 
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
<form action="image_upload_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="portfolio-upload" id="image-upload">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
<br />
</form>
```

**HELP!**

Answer (score 0):

Would you want to try moving the code within the document.ready() in image_upload.php into the same function in the port_edit.php and try again? I am not sure this would work, but you could try that...

Like below:

**port_edit.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshWindow() {
    location.reload(true);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery-display').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load($link.attr('href')).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Gallery Display',
            width: 280,
            height: 280,
            close: refreshWindow,
            resizable: false

        });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });

    // attach handler to form's submit event
    $('#image-upload').submit(function() {
        // submit the form
        $(this).ajaxSubmit();
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
<a href="image_upload.php" id="gallery-display">Modify</a>
```

**image_upload.php**

```
<form action="image_upload_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="portfolio-upload" id="image-upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
    <br />
</form>
```

Comment: I actually tried this before and while it no longer actually goes to image_upload_action.php as if it's a link (which is good), I can't seem to get the dialog to close, alert or anything after the submission is successful.

Comment: You would need an explicit `$dialog.dialog('close')` to close the dialog you opened.